# Loading image for JAI API

Tags: java, image, api, jai

I am trying to load an image from my computer into a code to produce a color histogram. My code is compiling but it says that the image is not found, although it is on the Home part of my laptop as 'me.jpg.' Below is the first part of my code, Any tips?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.renderable.ParameterBlock;
import javax.media.jai.*;


public class test {
  public test() {
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    PlanarImage image = JAI.create("fileload", "me.jpg"); // Load Image
    int [][] imageHistogram = getHistogram(image);
    FileWriter writer = null;
    File outputFile = new File("test2.txt");
```

Comment: This will work only if you launch your program in the same directory where your image file is located. Also check file name case if you are using case sensitive OS.

Comment: I am working in terminal on a Mac. So could I make a folder and save my image and my code to the same directory?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you store your code and your data (images) in different, proper, places.

Then, open the terminal and set the data directory as the current directory. And invoke the JVM specifying the code directry into the classpath:

```
java -classpath <directory-of-code> my.class <parameters...>
```

**Update**

Also, you could pass the absolute path as a parameter and receive it in your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PlanarImage image = JAI.create("fileload", args[0]);
    ...
```

And the command line:

```
java -classpath <directory-of-code> my.class my-home/me.jpg
```

Comment: I have it specified to exactly where the image is located, and it is still not working. I am sorry if this is a silly question, this is my last class assignment and I am just not sure how to load an image.